# How to prevent a particular application like YouTube from starting?

Tags: android

Basically I want to prevent a particular application from starting. A further question may be related to the Android internal behaviors from clicking application button to application running. Help clarifying each internal step will be highly appreciated.

Put it in detail: When the user clicks 'YouTube' button on the screen (assuming YouTube has not been started by far), who gets to know first this particular click is YouTube? Also, I think finally Zygote will spawn a new process representing YouTube, and this process will be written in process table in kernel. Should I let Zygote know this is an application that the user should not start?

Answer (score 0):

If the user starts an app by clicking on an app icon per default you won't be able to intercept it.

You might be able to do something if you made your own launcher application which had it's own shortcuts to all apps that reside on the phone. That would be my best suggestion to a possible work around.

Comment: Thank you and I am sorry I did not come back to this thread quickly. My solution would be working with ActivityManager, then you can discover package name.